# How was my MFP able to save scanned document to my computer without a password?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-sharing, smb, scanner

I was scanning document with Canon MB2100 and it asked me where to save it. I choose "Computer" and it showed my Windows computer in a format

```
username (SMBNAME)
```

It didn't ask any passwords, but after finish, the scanned files appeared in `My Documents`. I don't have any shares without a password (I think).

How was it possible?

It showed only one computer from my `LAN` and files went to `My Documents` of one user on it.

Comment: Have you previously installed drivers/print utility etc on the computer? Usually, that's the point trust is established.

Comment: Yes, I have installed it on two computers. How to control this trust?